# Adyen Apple Pay with Drop-In on web click not working

Tags: reactjs, applepay, adyen

I have integrated Apple Pay with Adyen using Drop-in configuration. Apple pay option is visible in payment form but clicking on it does nothing and if I double click on it, it prints

"Unhandled Promise Rejection: InvalidAccessError: Page already has an active payment session."

If I run same website on iPhone -> Safari browser and clicking on apple pay in drop-in payment form it opens payment sheet but closes it print "could not create any session".

I am using Adyen Apple Certificate.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running it with https protocol? I can't see from your screenshot. I remember this was a requirement for successfully trigger the paymentSheet when developing. Also do you have a test appleID which has cards in apple wallet? also needed to trigger the payment sheet. You can follow this documentation to create an In App Test User in iTunes Connect—
you should not use other accounts as doing so will result in prompts to enter your actual credit card number and other information.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282009a
I hope these remarks help.

Comment: @NeveenAtik I found the solution, actual the problem was, I was not signed-in on Mac using Apple Account. that's what created the issue

Comment: Great to hear that @PankajMundra, and thanks Neveen for helping out.

It is a great idea if you can add the solution as the answer (for future reference).

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully trigger payment sheet there are several requirements by Apple API:

- Use https protocol
- use appleID test account you can follow [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282009a) to create an In App Test User in iTunes Connect— you should not use other accounts as doing so will result in prompts to enter your actual credit card number and other information.
- Add test payment cad to apple wallet